# Models are printing with a scratch on the side

Tags: print-quality, ultimaker-cura, pla, troubleshooting, creality-ender-3

I just recently got an Ender 3 and have been trying to learn the do’s and don’ts. My first model looked like it had under extrusion and stringing, but my second model looks like it has frequent “scratches” along the sides. I printed it with two materials, a white sample PLA that came with, and a black Sunlu PLA.

[image: Print showing lines on side of print]

I could use some insight on how to improve it, I’m seeking to make some fairly smooth looking models similar to Fat Dragon games.

Comment: Hi Scarrol, welcome to 3DPrinting.SE! Please use the SE internal image storage instead of external links. The SE images are retained for as long as SE exists, links to external sites may suffer from link rot after some time.

Comment: What is meant by Fat Dragon games?

Comment: Along with what @0scar stated, an image with resolution to see detail would greatly improve our understand of what you're talking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertical lines you are referring too are the result of [ringing or vibration](https://www.simplify3d.com/support/print-quality-troubleshooting/vibrations-and-ringing/). This is commonly encountered with high print speeds, high acceleration values or if a sudden change in direction takes place.

This can be solved by printing slower, decreasing acceleration values and checking for mechanical issues. E.g. the belts may be too flexible (or contain a tension spring) or there may be a loose part somewhere.

Comment: Thanks! I tightened the z axis belt and it seems to have done the trick. Gonna run a couple more prints and see how it goes. Will adjust as you recommend!

Comment: That is probably the X axis belt you refer too, which falls in the mechanical issues category.